# Dynamic Forms Builder, CRUD Submissions, Multiple Files Upload Using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In our current application there is a new requirement of our client.As they told that they need n numbers of forms at different stages of their business and those are changing time to time. Even a new forms can be added. Their requirement is once the product is delivered to them they will not come back to us again and again for each change and will create those form by their own.

Simply they want a user interface where they can create the form by drag and drop manner.

What they want :

In our application there will be a form building section where a non technical person can be able to create a form.
Mapping the controls with existing data of their existing database so that the form is populated with the corresponding data ( data will be inserted into the database using another user interface).
Once the data is populated they will take the print out of the filled up form and will proceed as per their business flow.
As they introduce new form time to time we can't provide any predefined template to them and they are not agree to design the form in HTML.

Is there any way of doing this in Asp.Net MVC (without using any CMS ).

Comment: You are going to create your own CMS if not using any existing CMS. Yes you can do this in asp.net mvc. But how to build a CMS in ASP.NET MVC is not an answer you can get here in StackOverflow. You are not talking about solving a single programming problem but you are talking about a completing a whole project.

Comment: What the client wants is hard, this is why CMSs tend to cost a lot of money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a number of asp.net forms builders. And I been wanting to build my own for years. (you store the control, the location etc in a database, or even as xml, and then on page load, read the xml, and crank out the controls and layout into the page. We all built these for desktop, and you can do the same for the web.

The open source evolutility project has a FANTASTIC system for this, but it does NOT include the GUI part. But, it would be a good start. You would have to build the GUI part, but the rendering part, and save of the forms layout is all done for you. So, your forms builder would offer a set of controls to drop and move around in the form. When you save, you would have a corresponding "xml" markup bit that you save to the one "forms layout" file. On forms load, you read that xml file and produce the form (that's the part evolutility does for you). So, you need the part that has each control in a tool box (along with the xml for that control). you drop control into form, and add the xml to the "form layout in xml".

As I stated, evolutility has all the parts to render forms and layout and place controls on the final finished form for display - it just don't have a GUI for doing this part.

You can look at the project here:

http://evolutility.com/

there are others. But, it really depends on how complex of a form builder or content builder you wish to make.

But, a xml, or json based layout and definition of the controls placed on a page is a good start. You could store such "layout" information in a database. Heck have a classic master to child table, and thus save each control in evolutiity format, and simple append then all together, and then have evolutility render that xml into a working form for you.

I don't know of a open source project that combines both the "layout" and "define" of the controls AND ALSO has a GUI to build the forms. But, to be fair, the hard part (how to layout, and how to have each control defined in some json (or xml) is done for you.